# What is "copying a frog" in Pocket Frogs?

Tags: pocket-frogs

In Pocket Frogs, I keep hearing about keeping copies of frogs. How do you copy a frog? I just started this game a couple of days ago so I'm still trying to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could catalog it, then buy a copy from the catalog...